# how to parse the second xml tree in a file

Tags: python, xml, lxml, scrapy

Suppose I have a XML file like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<items>
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <items>
    <item>
      <price>1500</price>
      <info> asfgfdff</info>
    </item>
  </items>
```

How do I parse so that the parser selects the recently updated xml tree?

Comment: Do you literally repeat the first two lines or is it just a copy & paste mistake?

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I'm pretty sure that xml files cannot have multiple declarations (<?...?>), unless they are contained in a CDATA section.

Comment: yes i literally repeat it.. whenever i crawl through a website i save it in a file.So, when i try to parse it i get this error `lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document, line 2, column 6
`

Comment: i mean the data extracted is saved that way

Comment: Like João Lourenço stated, double XML prolog declaration is not valid XML. And that's precisely what the lxml parser is telling you:
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>", it's complaining about that second xml declaration.
This resembles more of an XML soup, so until you correct the way you're saving the data, you'll not be able to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('file','r') as f:
    newestXml = []
    for line in f.readlines():
        if re.search('^<\?xml',line):
            newestXml = [line]
        else:
            newestXml.append(line)
```

At the end of the loop, `newestXml` will contain all the lines from the last occurrence of `<?xml` to the end of the file.
Now you can combine the lines and use the xml parser to parse the xml.

Note - I can't check this code now, so it may contain small mistakes, but I hope the idea will help you.

Comment: Not sure about this - newestXml would contain the 'inner' xml doc plus closing tags for the 'outer' doc, e.g. </item>). Using regexp with XML is a can of worms!